# Can I use hot water for skim milk powder?

Tags: milk

I was trying to make milk tea from skim milk powder and black tea bags today, and found that after adding hot water to skim milk powder, that powder doesn't fully dissolve in the water. There are lots of white tiny particles in the hot water that doesn't disappear after 20 minutes.

I checked the instructions and it said use cold water to mix the powder. Are the white particles I saw normal? Or are they only a result of me incorrectly using hot water?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have similar issues when mixing with cold water? If so, it could be the product that's the issue, not the temperature.

Comment: By particles do you meam small "bubbles" similar to when clumps of flour in a cake batter or same as bechamel when adding flour to hot butter? (Or even like a not well mixed protein shake)

Answer (score 1):

I always use hot water and it has worked fine. In fact i find milk powder dissolves quickly in hot water than cold.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with skim milk powder and coffee. The particles float to the top of my cup. If you mix with a bit of cold water first to make a paste, then add the hot coffee or water, it might work better. I simply threw it out and bought coffee mate.

Comment: In my experience, the older the milk powder, the more likely it is to have trouble dissolving properly — especially if the pack was opened a while ago. Maybe the powder gets moist, or the milk fats go rancid, or some other process occurs. A creamer such as Coffee Mate isn't a good option for tea, unfortunately… (BTW, here in the UK it's called ‘skimmed’ milk, because it has been skimmed. ‘Skim milk’ is a command!)